# Return value from coroutine scope without runBlocking

Tags: android, kotlin, android-asynctask, kotlin-coroutines, coroutine

I am trying to run a function based on the response data of a repo call, and running into an issue with race conditions / returning data using coroutine scope. Based on the two pseudo code blocks, I was wondering if I could get some help?

Option 1: Can't return a response within a coroutine scope without using runBlocking.

```
fun mainFunction(): Boolean {
  return subFunction(getResponse()) //returns boolean
}

private fun getResponse () {
  scope.launch{
    val response = async { someApiCall }.await()

    return response
  }
}
```

Option 2: The `response` value is not initialized by the time the `subFunction` is called, thus leading to an error.

```
lateinit var response: MutableList<>

fun mainFunction(): Boolean {
  return subFunction(response) //returns boolean
}

private fun getResponse () {
  scope.launch{
    response = async { someApiCall }.await()
  }
}
```

Comment: A method that runs a suspending method and returns a result should be a `suspend` method itself. Why isn't your `getResponse()` suspending?

Comment: As @ianhanniballake mentioned, `getResponse` should be `suspend fun`. And you can use `withContext(Dispatchers.IO)`. Then in `mainFunction`, you can use `scope.launch`, `async await` is not required.

Comment: You can use `withContext` to return from the block

Comment: If I need to return a value (like a boolean) for the ```mainFunction```, is it possible to handle the ```getResponse``` return without making it a suspend function or ```withContext```? Because if we use it within a coroutine in the ```mainFunction```, it will only return type `Unit` right? @TuanChau @ianhanniballake @Anania Jemberu

Comment: Yes that is true, I have faced this situation too. I made that function suspend and called it inside runBlocking block in my fragment.

Comment: If you want to return something with `mainFunction`, you can make it `suspend fun` and call `getResponse` without `withContext()` or `scope.launch`. Let me create an answer for demonstration.

Answer (score 0):

Case 1: Main function returns something

```kotlin
suspend fun mainFunction(): Boolean = subFunction(getResponse())

fun subFunction(input: Response): Boolean {
    // Do something
    return something
}

suspend fun getResponse() = withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
    someApiCall()
}
```

Then the caller of `mainFunction` is kick-and-forget, we can use `scope.launch`.

```kotlin
fun metaMainFunction() {
    scope.launch {
        val isSomething = mainFunction()
        // Do something with isSomething
    }
}
```

Case 2: `mainFunction` is kick-and-forget, we apply the same behavior to `metaMainFunction` of case 1

```kotlin
fun mainFunction() {
    scope.launch {
        val response = getResponse()
        // Do something with response
    }
}
```

The best practice is the callee should decide which thread it is executed. In this case, we should always use `withContext(Dispatchers.IO)` for `getResponse()`.